# Error running Android App that uses OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, emulation

When I ran  code using opencv on the Android emulator the following error was displayed on the emulator's screen:

OPENCV MANAGER PACKAGE NOT FOUND. TRY TO INSTALL IT?

The code was successfully built and installed.

I saw the following in LogCat:

1. Trying to install opencv library
2. Cannot connect to opencv manager
3. Emulator without gpu emulation detected
4. Trying to install opencv manager via google play
5. Google play service is not installed

I followed the steps mentioned in the following site to link  ndk and opencv

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html

and

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html#android-binary-package-with-ndk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> OPENCV MANAGER PACKAGE NOT FOUND. TRY TO INSTALL IT?

Did you read error message? You just have to install OpenCV Manager package (download from android market or install APK from `samples` folder).

Comment: thanx a lot for ur reply... i installed the OpenCV_2.4.2_Manager.apk but after installing it the following was poping up OPENCV LIBRARY PACKAGE WAS NOT FOUND!TRY INSTALL IT! . after reading this i tried to install OpenCV_2.4.2_binary_pack_armv7a.apk  but this was not getting installed now what should i do..???

Comment: @HimanshuKohli you have to install it for your type of processor... If you want to develop some opencv app than I highly recommend you to read some programming books, because it seems that you are new in programming.

Comment: actually i have done some coding in opencv before but i am new to opencv with android.. i kindly request you to please elaborate on "you have to install it for your type of processor", and from where i can get the OPENCV LIBRARY PACKAGE...???

Comment: @HimanshuKohli Take a look at spec of your device and get the processor type (x86, armv6, armv7, armv7-neon). And please, don't CAPS HERE.

Comment: one more thing i just wanted to ask..
i had to install the following .apk for my emulator OpenCV_2.4.2_binary_pack_armv7a.apk  , now suppose i have an android device with a qualcomm processor then i'll have to install the opencv library package for that processor... right..??? so this makes it processor dependent...right..??